# ath10k driver not working, hence wifi adoptor QCA6164 not recognised

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

no additional drivers found except processor microcode firmware for Intel CPU under additional drivers,software and updates,settings. Hence i am not able to update the ath10k driver through settings. is there any way to update ath10k through terminal? and if updating doesn't work what should i do to make Ubuntu 16.04 recognize the WIFI adopter?

Comment: This helped me solve my wifi drop issue in ubuntu 18.04.3LTS as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063679/ath10k-and-qca6174-causing-pcie-errors-firmware-crashes-and-connection-drops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the procedure from there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940
and it will work

As a summary, and assuming you are on version 16.04, open a terminal:

```
 1. sudo rm -r /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/
 2. cd /tmp ; wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip
 3. unzip master.zip ; sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware-master/QCA6174/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
 4. cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/ ; sudo mv firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 firmware-5.bin
 5. cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/ ; sudo mv
    firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 firmware-4.bin
 6. sudo reboot
```

Comment: FYI, I did it myself and it worked perfectly with that procedure! (I've got a pc with embedded QCA6164 wifi adapter)

Comment: it worked like a charm as you said.  finally happy now, after four days of frustration. Thank you so much.