# DELL XPS 15 9570: ath10k qca6174 wifi Adapter crashing

Tags: networking, 18.04, atheros, xps, firmware

WiFi Keeps crashing. Adapted [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063679/ath10k-and-qca6174-causing-pcie-errors-firmware-crashes-and-connection-drops) to fix the problem, but still keeps crashing.

**Recovery Requires:**

```
Reboot
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

**System Information:**

Linux user1 4.20.13-042013-generic #201902270533 SMP Wed Feb 27 10:35:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
~ $lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

**Some logs:**

WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 was the Default firmware

=================================================================
**WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1**

```
[ 8323.906999] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[ 8323.907011] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400  11  11   3   3
[ 8323.907020] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800  17  17 158 159
[ 8323.907028] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  32  32  95  96
[ 8323.907036] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000  16  16  17  16
[ 8323.907045] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 3959 3959 253 189
[ 8323.907053] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0  64   0
[ 8323.907062] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  21  21  29  29
[ 8323.907070] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
[ 8324.260461] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 8324.276049] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 8324.279189] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 8324.402454] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: device successfully recovered
[ 8364.155855] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 8364.174069] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 8364.177040] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 9705.621579] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 9705.637791] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 9705.640827] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[10829.224206] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid ab2a9571-a602-44d9-83d5-df9048b0181e)
[10829.224221] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[10829.224226] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[10829.225712] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[10829.226881] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[10829.226888] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[10829.227088] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware register dump:
[10829.227098] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x000015B3 0x009951E2 0x00955B31
[10829.227105] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [04]: 0x009951E2 0x00060530 0x00000000 0x000A0AF8
[10829.227111] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [08]: 0x000A05B4 0x000A0AF8 0x0040F6E0 0x000A34B4
[10829.227117] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[10829.227123] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x00910712 0x00000000 0x0091080D
[10829.227129] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [20]: 0x409951E2 0x0040E5B8 0x0040E720 0x0040E6CD
[10829.227136] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [24]: 0x809945FE 0x0040E618 0x0300FFFF 0xC09951E2
[10829.227142] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [28]: 0x80995FD9 0x0040E678 0x000A05B4 0x0040F6E0
[10829.227148] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [32]: 0x80996BA5 0x0040E6B8 0x00000E50 0x00000000
[10829.227154] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [36]: 0x8098736D 0x0040E7D8 0x00000000 0x004089F0
[10829.227160] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [40]: 0x809ABF81 0x0040E808 0x004089F0 0x00417360
[10829.227166] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [44]: 0x809A65F4 0x0040E948 0x0041FED0 0x00434790
[10829.227172] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [48]: 0x809A5D4B 0x0040E988 0x0040E9AC 0x0042D36C
[10829.227177] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [52]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9A8 0x00000002 0x00000001
[10829.227184] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [56]: 0x809FDBC5 0x0040EA58 0x0043D720 0x0042D718
[10829.227189] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[10829.227211] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400  11  11   3   3
[10829.227228] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800  22  22 355 356
[10829.227245] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  15  15  78  79
[10829.227262] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000   1   1   2   1
[10829.227280] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4267 4267 151  87
[10829.227303] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0  64   0
[10829.227326] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00   2   2   2   2
[10829.227350] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
[10829.569451] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[10829.586721] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[10829.590026] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[10829.699620] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: device successfully recovered
```

=================================================================
**WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00128-QCARMSWPZ-1**

```
~ $dmesg | grep ath1
[    4.087839] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.091810] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    4.414285] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    4.414286] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.414588] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00128-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 4c523412
[    4.488459] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[    4.571715] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    4.587029] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    4.590053] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    4.590572] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: htt-ver 3.56 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    4.721801] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0 wlp59s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.437195] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    5.452443] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[    5.455446] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 2217.866930] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid b5cb4fdf-436b-4d38-a62b-9eae48914381)
[ 2217.866936] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[ 2217.866937] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 2217.867347] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00128-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 4c523412
[ 2217.867656] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[ 2217.867659] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: htt-ver 3.56 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[ 2217.867794] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: firmware register dump:
[ 2217.867797] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x000015B3 0x00995396 0x00955B31
[ 2217.867800] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [04]: 0x00995396 0x00060530 0x00000000 0x000A0AF8
[ 2217.867802] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [08]: 0x000A05B4 0x000A0AF8 0x0040F6E0 0x000A34B4
[ 2217.867805] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[ 2217.867807] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x00910712 0x00000000 0x0091080D
[ 2217.867809] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [20]: 0x40995396 0x0040E5C8 0x0040E730 0x0040E6DD
[ 2217.867811] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [24]: 0x809947B2 0x0040E628 0x0300FFFF 0xC0995396
[ 2217.867814] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [28]: 0x80996182 0x0040E688 0x000A05B4 0x0040F6E0
[ 2217.867816] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [32]: 0x80996D09 0x0040E6C8 0x00000E50 0x00000000
[ 2217.867818] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [36]: 0x809874DB 0x0040E7D8 0x00000000 0x004089F0
[ 2217.867820] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [40]: 0x809AC149 0x0040E808 0x00417368 0x004089F0
[ 2217.867823] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [44]: 0x809A67BC 0x0040E948 0x00420120 0x00434A00
[ 2217.867825] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [48]: 0x809A5F13 0x0040E988 0x0040E9AC 0x0042D5CC
[ 2217.867827] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [52]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9A8 0x00000002 0x00000001
[ 2217.867829] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [56]: 0x809FE1B5 0x0040EA58 0x0043D990 0x0042D978
[ 2217.867831] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[ 2217.867847] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400  11  11   3   3
[ 2217.867859] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800   8   8 309 310
[ 2217.867871] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  21  21  20  21
[ 2217.867882] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000   3   3   4   3
[ 2217.867894] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 1425 1425  10 202
[ 2217.867906] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0  64   0
[ 2217.867918] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00   6   6  26  26
[ 2217.867927] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   0   0   0   0
[ 2218.207200] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 2218.222603] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 2218.225597] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 2218.289869] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: device successfully recovered
[ 2403.984652] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 2409.045798] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: wmi service ready event not received
[ 2409.127156] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Could not init core: -110
[ 2409.464996] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 2409.480834] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 2409.483866] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[ 2414.699264] WARNING: CPU: 11 PID: 0 at drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/htt_rx.c:46 ath10k_htt_rx_pop_paddr.isra.29+0xdd/0xf0 [ath10k_core]
[ 2414.699302]  snd_seq_dummy snd_seq_oss aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_rawmidi cryptd glue_helper ath10k_pci intel_cstate ath10k_core intel_rapl_perf snd_seq input_leds joydev dell_wmi ath dell_smbios snd_seq_device idma64 dcdbas mac80211 serio_raw snd_timer virt_dma snd dell_wmi_descriptor cfg80211 intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof mxm_wmi soundcore rtsx_pci_ms memstick mei_me mei intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device typec_ucsi intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone dell_smo8800 intel_hid int3400_thermal mac_hid acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid i915 kvmgt vfio_mdev mdev vfio_iommu_type1 vfio kvm rtsx_pci_sdmmc irqbypass i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm nvme drm_panel_orientation_quirks cfbfillrect psmouse cfbimgblt
[ 2414.699335] RIP: 0010:ath10k_htt_rx_pop_paddr.isra.29+0xdd/0xf0 [ath10k_core]
[ 2414.699350]  ath10k_htt_txrx_compl_task+0x3c9/0xe00 [ath10k_core]
[ 2414.699353]  ath10k_pci_napi_poll+0x54/0x110 [ath10k_pci]
[ 2414.699396] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: failed to pop paddr list: -2
[ 2456.101707] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[ 2456.117680] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[ 2456.120634] ath10k_pci 0000:3b:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
~ $
```